# Podman why do registries.conf need an registry when using alises?

Tags: podman

As the title say I have the following configuration in my registries.conf file

```
[aliases]
"postgres" = "docker.io/library/postgres"

[[registry]]
location = "docker.io"
```

But why can't I just use the alias postgres? Why do podman need the registry when the alias contains the full path?

Comment: You don't need the `[[registry]]` entry as far as I can tell. I just added the `[aliases]` section to an otherwise empty `~/.config/containers/registries.conf` and it worked fine.

Comment: @larsks doing as you suggests results in

      "/containers/registries.conf": validating short-name aliases: invalid alias "enforcing": must contain registry and repository"

Comment: Interesting. Seems to work for me. Maybe a version difference? I'm running 3.3.1.